# EntityDataSource Show Entity Data With It Navigation Properties

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework

Hi I have a entity that cold **Users** that have a navigation property **UsersData** that have a field "LastLoginDate".

What I want to do is use EntityDataSource to display some information of the users inside a GridView (I don't want to do it from code behind with linq) .

I tried to use ***Include*** property of EntityDataSource but I don't know how use them in my gridview to select LastLoginDate field can anyone help me ?
it's need to be a very basic thing to do, show a relation table field... 
This is my code:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=MyModelEntities" DefaultContainerName="ModelEntities" 
    EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" 
    EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="Users" Include="UsersData" AutoGenerateWhereClause="True" 
    EnableFlattening="False">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the relation between Users and UsersData is of multiplicity 1:1 you can try to add to your grid field like:

```
<asp:BoundField DataFiled="UsersData.LastLoginDate" HeaderText="Last Login" />
```

Where UsersData is name of your navigation property in User entity. Similarly you can try use Eval expression in TemplateField:

```
<%# Eval("UsersData.LastLoginDate") %>
```